# Как сделать кнопку неактивной в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Допустим мне нужно сделать эту кнопку неактивной:

```
tkinter.Button(win, text='Кнопка', font='Arial 18').place(x=80, y=230, width=100, height=35)
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Disable / Enable Button in TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580507/disable-enable-button-in-tkinter)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580507/disable-enable-button-in-tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Button')
button.pack()

button['state'] = 'disabled'
# или через метод config: button.config(state='disabled')

root.mainloop()
```

Для активации нужно установить значение `'normal'`:

```
button['state'] = 'normal'
# или через метод config: button.config(state='normal')
```